# suppose that $V$ is a finite dimensional and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $\dim U = \dim V$. Prove $U = V$

Tags: linear-algebra

I get stuck in this exercise. Can some one give me a hand? It is from *Linear Algebra Done Right*, from Sheldon Axler.

Comment: Consider a basis of $U$. Perhaps it is also a basis of $V$.

Comment: What do you know about the concept of "dimension" in linear algebra? List a couple of properties, and see if you can't find one which you can use as leverage to your advantage.

Comment: Ajotaxe, i did it, in my proof the basis of V must be equal to the basis of U, to V=U. But i really dont know if is what the exercice propose. I assume that existe v belonging to V that must belong to U as well. And i open up everything with a linear combination. then i did v-v, and again open up as a linear combination. I got b1.u1 + ... + bn.un = a1v1 + ... + anvn. But i really think this is wrong, or not a good proof.

Comment: Arthur, i will try again. And see if i miss something.

Comment: @ajotatxe if U is a subspace of V and in this case dim U = dim V, then the basis of U must be the same of V, by definition ?

Comment: Then is not $U=V$?

Comment: yes, i guess. I'm still not understending, why the basis of U must be equal to the basis of V. Is because U is subspace of V ?

Comment: Can i argument that:  #U = n, #V = n and V intercection with U is equal U and the intercection of U with V is equal V so V = U ?